# Object Recognition with Intel Realsense D415

Tags: python, opencv, realsense

Hello i am working on a project with python and tensorflow model training i want the camera to detect the trained images in the camera and show the distance from the camera to that object e.g book pen..
this is the code i am using:

my problem is how to add the distance measurement to this code and show it on the recognized image

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs import numpy as np import cv2 import tensorflow as tf

Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

print("[INFO] Starting streaming...")
pipeline.start(config)
print("[INFO] Camera ready.")

print("[INFO] Loading model...")
PATH_TO_CKPT = "frozen_inference_graph_coco.pb"


detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)

image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

print("[INFO] Model loaded.")
colors_hash = {}
while True:
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
    scaled_size = (color_frame.width, color_frame.height)
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(color_image, axis=0)
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                                             feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
    scores = np.squeeze(scores)

    for idx in range(int(num)):
        class_ = classes[idx]
        score = scores[idx]
        box = boxes[idx]

        if class_ not in colors_hash:
            colors_hash[class_] = tuple(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))

        if score > 0.6:
            left = int(box[1] * color_frame.width)
            top = int(box[0] * color_frame.height)
            right = int(box[3] * color_frame.width)
            bottom = int(box[2] * color_frame.height)

            p1 = (left, top)
            p2 = (right, bottom)
            r, g, b = colors_hash[class_]
            cv2.rectangle(color_image, p1, p2, (int(r), int(g), int(b)), 2, 1)

    cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow('RealSense', color_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

print("[INFO] stop streaming ...")
pipeline.stop()
```

PS:I am a beginner and i am working in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

so you would first need to enable the depth camera stream, and then align the depth stream to the colour stream. This would enable you to obtain `(1280, 720, 3)` image and depth matrices *(The depth matrix is 3 channeled only when you colourise the image using maybe `cv2.applyColourMap` or `rs.colorizer()`)*.

Now, let us assume you have detected an object at `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` in your image, using TensorFlow as you have mentioned in your sample code. You can now enquire the depth matrix *(original, **not colorised**)* about the depth values within this box coordinates. This will give you the raw depth values at the box location. However, you will also need another piece of information, the depth scale, which you can obtain from the depth sensor using `profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor().get_depth_scale()`. When you multiply the depth values within the region `x1, y1, x2, y2` in the depth matrix with the depth scale and you would have the depth of the object.

You can refer to the [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/jupyter/notebooks/distance_to_object.ipynb).

You can take a look at this boilerplate code for your python script. I have omitted the section about the object detection because this is something you have already done.

```py
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.namedWindow("Colour Image", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.namedWindow("Depth Image", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()

wrapper = rs.pipeline_wrapper(pipeline)
profile = config.resolve(wrapper)

colorizer = rs.colorizer()
depth_scale = profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor().get_depth_scale()

print(f"Depth scale:{depth_scale}")

config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 1280, 720, rs.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
pipeline.start(config)

align = rs.align(rs.stream.color)

while True:
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    frames = align.process(frames)
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
    depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()

    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
    depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())

    # Insert your object detection code here

    # I assume that I detected an object at [200, 200, 400, 400]

    # Draw the bounding box
    cv2.rectangle(color_image, (200, 200), (400, 400), (0, 255, 255), 1)
    cv2.rectangle(depth_image, (200, 200), (400, 400), (0, 255, 255), 1)

    depth = depth_image[200:400, 200:400].astype(float)

    depth = depth * depth_scale

    dist = cv2.mean(depth)

    cv2.putText(color_image, f"Depth: {dist} m", (200, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, (0,0,0), 1)
    cv2.imshow("Colour Image", color_image)
    cv2.imshow("Depth Image", depth_image)



    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: # Escape key closes the window(s)
        break

pipeline.stop()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```